# Modify softmax function base in python

Tags: python

I apologies if the question is poorly framed. I have close to zero knowledge of programming and just want to modify the pre-existing code.

I have a script where `softmax` function is defined as:

```py
def softmax(x):
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
    return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)
```

If I am reading right, this is taking *e* as base. I want to change it to base 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The softmax is

[image]

If you want to change `e` to `10` then you can change it to

```
return np.power(10,x) / np.sum(np.power(10,x), axis=0)
```